# Attach EBS Volumes to another ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance A which has 2 EBS volumes(1 is root volume)
Now I have another instance B which will be like a replacement
I need to detach the volumes from A and attach it to B
How to do this efficiently?

1.lsblk

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

nvme0n1     259:2    0    8G  0 disk

└─nvme0n1p1 259:3    0    8G  0 part /

nvme1n1     259:0    0  100G  0 disk

└─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0  100G  0 part

2.sudo file -s /dev/nvme1n1

3.sudo mkdir /data

4.sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

```
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

dmesg | tail :

[   14.095862] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored

[ 2183.351722]  nvme1n1: p1

**I am getting this error**

sudo lsblk -f :

NAME        FSTYPE LABEL           UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT

nvme0n1

└─nvme0n1p1 ext4   cloudimg-rootfs e4e7b145-d90a-4248-b083-e6790a0e48fb /

nvme1n1

└─nvme1n1p1 ext4   cloudimg-rootfs 813a48d1-3b8f-4bf1-b007-d36d47665949

Comment: Did you check aws docs on how to attach and detach ebs volumes? If yes, what exactly is unclear?

Comment: @Marcin I have created a volume from snapshot and attached to the B instance but while mounting I am getting error

Comment: @kc7 what is the error you are getting while attaching the volume to instance B ?
Assuming you have referred https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-detaching-volume.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

Comment: I was trying to mount the disk but when I tried to mount the partition it worked..I have added the error in description for reference..So mounting the partition nvme1n1p1 worked for me